# Meteor 'createUser' throws "MongoError: assertion src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp:109"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So in my Meteor app there is a section that allows for account creation. It asks for a username, password, and to confirm the password.  This was working perfectly until last night where it now throws the Mongo Error shown below.  My coworker has not experienced this issue despite being on the same SVN revision as me.  This leads me to believe it is an issue with Mongo on my machine only. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling meteor but that did not fix it.

**Exception**

```
I20150909-12:22:03.390(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'createUser' MongoError: assertion src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp:109
    I20150909-12:22:03.390(-4)?     at Object.Future.wait (/home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.xvre8c++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     at [object Object].<anonymous> (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1)
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     at [object Object].MongoConnection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:678:1)
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (packages/mongo/collection.js:575:1)
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     at Object.Accounts.insertUserDoc (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1017:1)
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     at createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:718:1)
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     at packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:738:1
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     at tryLoginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:161:1)
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     at Object.Accounts._loginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:277:1)
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:724:1)
    I20150909-12:22:03.391(-4)?     - - - - -
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at Object.toError (/home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.11t75li++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at /home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.11t75li++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:116:29
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at /home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.11t75li++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1195:7
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at /home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.11t75li++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at Server.Base._callHandler (/home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.11t75li++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:453:41)
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at /home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.11t75li++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:487:18
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at [object Object].MongoReply.parseBody (/home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.11t75li++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.11t75li++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:445:20)
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at [object Object].emit (events.js:95:17)
    I20150909-12:22:03.392(-4)?     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.1.0.11t75li++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:207:13)
```

**MongoDB Log**

```
"2015-09-09T12:22:03.231-0400 [conn5] uh oh: 16560",
        "2015-09-09T12:22:03.232-0400 [conn5] meteor.users Assertion failure n >= 0 && n < static_cast<int>(_files.size()) src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp 109",
        "2015-09-09T12:22:03.245-0400 [conn5] meteor.users 0xff19a6 0xf9b8f2 0xf84087 0xdacb78 0xdad2dd 0xddceba 0xddd17d 0xddd1e7 0xde5674 0xde4fc2 0x8f5259 0x8f75ce 0x9ed58d 0x9edf09 0x9eed67 0x9ef78d 0x9f2aef 0xa024b4 0xa03696 0xa0479e \n /home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.xvre8c++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x26) [0xff19a6]\n /home/tjhaigh/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.xvre8c++os.linux.x86_64+web.brows"
```

I guess it should be noted that I am running Fedora 22. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reseting you database? I would also recommend trying to connect to a "remote" mongo instance by specifying `MONGO_URL=` variable when you start the `meteor` process. The url may point to your local mongoDB server.